# Duplicates in a map

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I currently have an XSLT function that loads key=value pairs from a text file into a map.

```
<xsl:function name="myns:loadMapping" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:variable name="mapping" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:for-each select="unparsed-text-lines($inputFile,$fileEncoding)">
                <!-- Takes only lines which are in the form abc=xyz and are not comments (does not start with #) -->
                <xsl:if test="contains(.,'=') and not(starts-with(.,'#'))">
                    <xsl:map-entry key="substring-before(.,'=')" select="substring-after(.,'=')"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$mapping"/>
</xsl:function>
```

The function works fine unless the user tries to load a file containing duplicates, in which case the XSLT transform fails with an error (expected behaviour):

```
Error evaluating (map:merge(...)) on line xyz column xy of xyz.xsl:
  XTDE3365: Duplicate key in constructed map: {keyInError}
```

Is there a way I could catch this case and keep the transformation from aborting, something like this :

```
<xsl:function name="myns:loadMapping" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:variable name="mapping" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:for-each select="unparsed-text-lines($inputFile,$fileEncoding)">
                <!-- Takes only lines which are in the form abc=xyz and are not comments (does not start with #) -->
                <xsl:if test="contains(.,'=') and not(starts-with(.,'#'))">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="...map contains key...">
                            <xsl:message>Map already contains key. Please check input file.</xsl:message>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:map-entry key="substring-before(.,'=')" select="substring-after(.,'=')"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$mapping"/>
</xsl:function>
```

I see that there is something implemented for a future XSLT 4.0 release ([Saxon - Controlling duplicates on xsl:map](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/v4extensions/xslt-syntax-extensions/xsl-map-duplicates.html)) but I would like to stick to XSLT 3.0 for the time being.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Martin Honnen's suggestions, you could use `xsl:iterate` instead of `xsl:for-each`, passing the map as a parameter, which would allow you to inspect the map before adding another entry to it.

```
<xsl:iterate select="...">
  <xsl:param name="map" select="map{}"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="map:contains($map, ...)">...</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:next-iteration>
        <xsl:with-param name="map" select="map:put($map, ..., ...)"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, both `map:merge` in XPath 3.1 or of course grouping with e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="unparsed-text-lines($inputFile,$fileEncoding)[contains(.,'=') and not(starts-with(.,'#'))]" group-by="substring-before(., '=')">
  <xsl:map-entry key="current-grouping-key()" select="substring-after(., '=')"/>
  <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
    <xsl:message>..</xsl:message>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

allow you more control than your approach without having to wait for XSLT 4 or trying to use experimental extensions.